# Does EF Core contain a feature that auto-generates reference tables from enums?

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I'm fairly certain I successfully used this feature a few months ago but I can't find any official or unofficial documentation of it now.

I know there's an existing third party nuget package to do it, but I don't recall using it.

Does Entity Framework Core have a feature that automatically generates reference tables from enums if they're used in the model classes? Or am I imagining it?

Comment: EF translates enums to integers.

Comment: That is the usual behaviour, yes. But I recall reading that it was a new feature of EF Core. I also recall doing it briefly in a project, but I can't find any documentation about it so this is my last resort before I have to conclude that I must have used a nuget package and forgotten about it. But I still don't think that's the case.

Comment: I personally have never heard of one such feature, can you provide more details?

Comment: @Ricardo it was super simple. I used an enum in my model class and a reference table was generated that represented my enum.

Comment: Weird, I use enums all the time...

Comment: There is no such feature, at least in EF-Core